# Facebook Permission Redirects Index when click another page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

As title says I have a strange problem. When I click another link on my index page,it redirects to index again. I'm writing the same permission code on both pages.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 


$code = $_REQUEST["code"];

if(empty($code)) {
    $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
        . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&scope=email,publish_stream,offline_access";

    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
}

$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
    . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&client_secret="
    . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code . "&scope=email,publish_stream,offline_access";

$access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

$graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?" . $access_token;

$user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));

?>
```

I'm writing this code all pages that I've linked on my index.

Is my code wrong, have a server problem or something else ?

Answer (score 0):

Do the URLs in the links on the index page contain a `code` variable. If it's not explicitly declared in the query string portion of URL the Oauth dialog will be triggered and, if the app is already installed, the user will be redirected to `$my_url`.

On a side note, judging from your code you could benefit from using the existing [Facebook PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/). Here's a code snippet that uses the current (v3.0.0) SDK that contains the behaviour listed above:

```
require 'facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
));

$fb_user_id = $facebook->getUser();

if ($fb_user_id) {
  try {
    $user = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    $fb_user_id = null;

    $params = array(
        'redirect_uri' => $my_url,
        'scope' => 'email,publish_stream,offline_access' );

    $dialog_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);

    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
  }
}
```